# dispatching inside actions in action creator

Tags: redux, react-redux

Can we use dispatch inside action creators and what purpose do they serve inside action creators ?
Here is a sample modified code from codebase .

```
export default function xyz(data) {
    const url = ;
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(
            a()
        );
        callApi(url, REQUESTS.POST, HEADERS, data).then((response) =>{
            dispatch(
                b(data)
            );
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(
                c(error.toString())
            );
        });
    };
}
// this returns  a type (an object) 
export function a() {
    return {
        type: xyzzzz
    };
}
Similarly we have b and c returning either type or say objects .
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dispatch multiple actions in an action.

I usually put a dispatch on an asychnronous action like this

```
function action() => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    let payload;

    dispatch('before-request');
    try {
      await someAsyncProcess();
      payload = { status: 'success' };
    } catch (err) {
      payload = { status: 'failure' };
    }
    dispatch('after-request', payload);
  };
}
```